# PHP - Sort arrays of rgb color codes by dominance

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, colors

I have an array with multiples rgb color codes :

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 255
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 125
        [1] => 20
        [2] => 255
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100
        [1] => 255
        [2] => 0
    )
```

[0] is red [1] is green and [2] is blue
I previously sorted this array with `array_multisort($r,SORT_DESC,$g,SORT_DESC,$b,SORT_DESC,$array_rgb_colors);`

I want to sort this array by color dominance : all red dominant first, then green, then blue. In my example, I will have :

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 255
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100 
        [1] => 255 
        [2] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 125
        [1] => 20
        [2] => 255
    )
```

I guess I need `usort`, but what could be the function ?

Comment: Did you tried any callback yet or are you asking to start from scratch?

Comment: When you say dominant do you mean that the color needs to be 255? How are they to be sorted if it is a larger array? Could you be more specific on your sorting pattern. Do you mean take the largest number of the three and use that as the main color?

Comment: Why do you want rgb(100,255,0) to be placed in front of rgb(125,20,255)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function main() {    
    $colors = [
        0 => [
            0 => 255,
            1 => 0,
            2 => 0
        ],
        1 => [
            0 => 125,
            1 => 20,
            2 => 255
        ],
        2 => [
            0 => 100,
            1 => 255,
            2 => 0
        ]
    ];

    $sortedColors = $this->sortByColor($colors);

    print_r($sortedColors);
}

public function sortByColor($colors) {
    $reds = [];
    $greens = [];
    $blues = [];
    $otherColors = [];
    $sortedArray = [];
    foreach($colors as $color) {
        if($color[0] > $color[1] && $color[0] > $color[2]) {
            $reds[] = $color;
        }
        elseif($color[1] > $color[0] && $color[1] > $color[2]) {
            $greens[] = $color;
        }
        elseif($color[2] > $color[0] && $color[2] > $color[1]) {
            $blues[] = $color;
        }
        else {
            $otherColors[] =$color;
        }
    }
    $sortedArray = array_merge($sortedArray, $reds);
    $sortedArray = array_merge($sortedArray, $greens);
    $sortedArray = array_merge($sortedArray, $blues);
    $sortedArray = array_merge($sortedArray, $otherColors);

    return $sortedArray;
}
```

This will sort your array and put all the color according to what is the largest number of the three colors then have the reds first then the greens then the blues. I think this is what you wanted.

The problem here is if all the numbers are the same they will be thrown into the othercolors array. You never said what you wanted to have happen in that case.

Comment: No problem It was fun to do

Answer (score 0):

Use uasort and compare in steps.. 
try following -

```
function my_sort($a,$b)
{
if($a==$b) return 0; 
if ($a[0]==$b[0])
    {
        if($a[1]==$b[1])
           {
              return ($a[2]<$b[2])?-1:1; //return comparing blue
           }
           return ($a[1]<$b[1])?-1:1;  //return comparing green
    }
return ($a[0]<$b[0])?-1:1; //return comparing red
}
uasort($arr,"my_sort"); // call your array here
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code from what i understand from your question 
Please note that it was just a sample you can try another approach for more optimized code

```
$array =  array(
  array('0' => '255','1' => '0','2' => '0'),
  array('0' => '125','1' => '20','2' => '255'),
  array('0' => '100','1' => '255','2' => '0'),
  array('0' => '125','1' => '20','2' => '255'),
  );

$colorArray = array('r'=>array('0' => '255','1' => '0','2' => '0'),
  'g'=>array('0' => '100','1' => '255','2' => '0'),
  'b'=>array('0' => '125','1' => '20','2' => '255'),
  );

$finalColor = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if($value == $colorArray['r']){
    $finalColor[$key] = $value;
  }
}

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if($value == $colorArray['g']){
    $finalColor[$key] = $value;
  }
}
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if($value == $colorArray['b']){
    $finalColor[$key] = $value;
  }
}


echo '<pre>';print_r($finalColor);
```

Comment: This will only work if the array only has those values. If they array had other values your code would not work.

Comment: Already said that as i understand from the question ... Also what array is posted